# Do interaction free experiments violate Quantum Physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions

Although I know that interaction free experiments come under Quantum Physics, Don't the kind of violate the Heisenberg uncertainty principle? Because you get a value without interacting with the particle. Can someone explain why this is false or true?

Comment: Give me an example of an interaction-free experiment. Without interactions, there's not any measurements. Without measurements, there's not really an experiment

Comment: The elitzur-vaidman bomb tester. You can also test for the position of a particle using mach-zehnder interferometers.

Comment: I have no idea why the elitzur-vaidman bomb tester is called interaction-free measurements. Dud bombs aren't interacted with but you can't tell if they are duds or live, so no measurement is really made. 50% of live bombs are interacted with. 25% of live bombs are impossible to distinguish from duds, so again no measurement is made. And the last 25% of live bombs aren't set off, but they are only measured by exerting an influence over the photon. That is still an interaction with the photon. The bomb may detonate when it absorbs a photon, but interaction $\ne$ absorption

Comment: Well that is the old one. The new model promises a almost 100% efficiency in interaction free experiments.